# Is this series convergent?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I'm guessing i can use the geometric rule (r < or > 1), but what do I do to get there?

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{1}{1+(2/3)^n}$$

Comment: do the terms go to zero?

Answer (score 3):

$$\Huge\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac 1{1+(2/3)^n}=\,\,\,\,\,??$$

Answer (score 2):

By the limit test, the series diverges:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{1}{1+\left(\frac23\right)^n}=\dfrac{1}{1+0}=1\neq0$$

Comment: How did you get (2/3)^n equal to 0?

Comment: It is a limit. $(2/3)^n$ goes to $0$.

Comment: To 'prove' that $(2/3)^n\to 0$ when $n\to\infty$ you can (for example): first, prove by induction that this inequality: $(2/3)^n<1/n$ holds for every integer $n\geq1$. Since $1/n\to0$ when $n\to\infty$ (which can be proven with the definition) and since $0<(2/3)^n<1/n$, we have by squeeze theorem that $(2/3)\to0$.